# Cannot trigger a function onClick when using a custom component with styled-components

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am experimenting with [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) and have seen that we can define a custom component easily such as:

```
const myButton = ({className, children}) => {
    <button className={className}>{children}</button>
}
```

However when I am using it in the rendered HTML, I cannot seem to get an event to trigger from the `onClick` handler attached...

```
<MyButton onClick={doSomething}>My custom button element</MyButton>
```

I have also tried attaching `onClick` to the defined const, including the function in that file:

```
const myButton = ({className, children}) => {
    <button className={className} onClick="{doSomething}">{children}</button>
}
```

But neither seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any reference to onClick function in your component. You should have something like this:

```
const myButton = ({className, children, onClick}) => {
    <button className={className} onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
}
```

In your example of attached onClick method, you attached the string instead of the function. Try something like this if above won't work:

```
const myButton = ({className, children}) => {
    <button className={className} onClick={() => alert("click!")}>{children}</button>
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The `basic` page didn't spell this out very clearly. My bad.

Comment: I also just realised that I have to do this if I wish to add an ID to the tag!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this right but I think you are trying to call doSomething function right ?

If so try this

```
<MyButton onClick={this.doSomething}>My custom button element</MyButton>
```

Or using arrow function

```
<MyButton onClick={() => this.doSomething}>My custom button element</MyButton>
```

Or if you are passing as a prop use

```
<MyButton onClick={props.doSomething}>My custom button element</MyButton>
```